# SQL Plus Columns getting overflowed to next row

Tags: sql, ubuntu, oracle11g, sqlplus

The DeptNo column when using SQLPlus in Oracle 11g XE is getting pushed down to the next row, despite having sufficient space in the window in Ubuntu 20.04 Terminal.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the size of the line using the following command:

```
SET LINES[IZE] 200 -- or more according to your requirement
```

Default line size by `SQL*Plus` is 80 and you can check it from your `SQL*Plus` as follows:

```
SQL> show lines
linesize 80
SQL> SET LINES 200 -- setting line size to 200
SQL> show lines -- checking now
linesize 200
SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, Is this a global setting?

Comment: This will set the linesize in particular session of sql*plus session

Comment: Is there any way that I can set this for every session by default? Like maybe changing it in the config file or something

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106169/sqldeveloper-set-default-linesize

This is one solution to set different line size by default

Comment: Yeap. You found it correctly @AmanAgarwal